# Cannot use CUDA on my Mac

Tags: gpu

I have a Mac Book Pro (High Sierra 10.13.6), with an Intel I7 processor and an NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M Graphics card with the very latest drivers installed. My problem is that when I look at the Systems tab in Blenders preferences I cannot see any mention of CUDA under the 'cycles compute device'. My graphics card is there with a ticked checkbox, but I just have a 'None' or 'OpenCL' option above that. How do I get the CUDA option to appear, so that I can use my GPU to render instead of my CPU?

Comment: What happens if you choose OpenCL?  Does that work?

Comment: Fairly certain that's been a known issue in Blender for a long time. OpenCL is the only option available across all Macs so far as I know. I think it might actually be Apple's fault, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do you have CUDA drivers installed with the nVidia Web driver? That was how I got it to work.

Comment: Hi Dale, I'm not sure that I'm getting anything from the OpenCL option, but then I don't know what to look for! I can use Cycles in the same way I can on my PC, but so far I'm stuck with CPU rendering.

Comment: Hi Samir, I've tried CUDA drivers from several sources including those downloaded from NVIDIA. I've now got the NVIDIA Driver manager installed. I would have hoped that using this would automatically ensure I was selecting the very best driver possible. Maybe I'm being naive!

Comment: I'm also a bit confused as to why Blender is even offering me OpenCL. I thought only AMD GPUs could use this? That seems odd as Blender clearly recognises that my NVIDIA GT750M is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Blender doesn't support gpus on Mac, I own a Macbook with Radeon 555x gpu and i7 - 9750H, and it can't render on gpu